# issues with getline overload function

Tags: c++, constants, cin

I am having issues with `cin.getline()`. When I put it into the below program, it is giving an error:

> no instance of overload function (ect) matches the argument list

I am also having an issue with my variable `nx`. The compiler says that it cannot be a constant, but I'm not sure how it is.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//create a class for one book
class Book
{
    //member variables
public:
    string title;
    string author;
    int year;

    //function to print the book details
    void print()
    {
        cout << "Title: " << title << endl;
        cout << "Authot: " << author << endl;
        cout << "Year: " << year << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string filename, temp;

    //prompt the user to enter the file name
    cout << "Enter filename: ";
    cin >> filename;

    //open the file
    fstream file;
    file.open(filename.c_str());

    int nx;
    //read the first line of the file to know the number of books
    file >> nx;
    //move to the next line of the file
    std::cin.getline(file, temp);

    //allocate an array of n Book
    
    Book books[nx];
   
    //read the data for n books from the file
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
    {
        //read file and initialize the books array
        std::cin.getline(file, books[i].title);
        std::cin.getline(file, books[i].author);
        file >> books[i].year;
        //move to the next line of the file
        getline(file, temp);
    }

    //Display the output
    cout << "Books found: " << nx << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nBook " << i + 1 << ":" << endl;
        cout << "Title: " << books[i].title << endl;
        cout << "Author: " << books[i].author << endl;
        cout << "Year: " << books[i].year << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The 2-parameter [`std::cin.getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) method does not take a `std::fstream` or a `std::string` as parameters.  It takes a `char*` and a `std::streamsize` instead, as it is meant to fill a `char[]` buffer.  To fill a `std::string` from a stream, you need to use the standalone [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function instead, eg:

```cpp
std::getline(file, temp);
...
std::getline(file, books[i].title);
...
```

As for the "constant" error relating to your `nx` variable, the problem is on this line:

```cpp
Book books[nx];
```

You are trying to declare a fixed-sized array using a size that is not known until runtime.  [You can't do that in *standard* C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/), an array's size must be known at compile-time instead.  Otherwise, you have to use `new[]` or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to allocate the array dynamically at runtime instead, eg:

```cpp
Book* books = new Book[nx];
...
delete[] books;
```

Or:

```cpp
#include <vector>

std::vector<Book> books(nx);
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/SyJlMu1ud)

---

On a side note:

When you want to discard content from an `istream` up to the next `'\n'` character, you can use the stream's [`ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) method instead of `std::getline()`, that way you are not wasting memory unnecessarily for an unused `std::string`, eg:

```cpp
#include <limits>

//move to the next line of the file
//std::getline(file, temp);
file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Also, you have defined a `print()` method in `Book`, but you are not actually using it.  Your final display loop can do this instead:

```
//Display the output
cout << "Books found: " << nx << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
{
    cout << "\nBook " << i + 1 << ":" << endl;
    /*
    cout << "Title: " << books[i].title << endl;
    cout << "Author: " << books[i].author << endl;
    cout << "Year: " << books[i].year << endl;
    */
    books[i].print();
}
```

Comment: This worked for line 36 but not line 46 and 47

Comment: It should work just fine for all of your uses of `getline()`. If you are having a particular problem, you need to update your question with the relevant details.

Comment: it still gives the same error for line 46 and 47 after I have done this

Comment: my issue is still the same as the original question I asked. It wasn't fixed.

Comment: You should not be getting that error with the code I have given you. `std::getline()` takes an `std::istream&` and an `std::string&` as parameters. `file` is an `std::fstream`, which derives from `std::istream`. A derived object can be assigned to a base-class reference. And `temp`, `Book::title`, and `Book::author` are `std::string`s, so they can all be passed to a `std::string&` reference, obviously.  So, if you are still getting errors, then the code you have shown here is not the real code you are actually working with, and you are not applying what I have said to your real code correctly.

Comment: this is what it is [saying](https://ibb.co/LrqFMWg)

Comment: That screenshot is of code that is NOT using the changes I have outlined for you.  NONE of this code should be using `std::cin.getline()` at all, only `std::getline()`.  And you are still allocating the `books` array incorrectly, too. I think you need to refresh this page, I don't think you are looking at the latest version of my answer.

Comment: when I take out the cin like you outlined it gives the same error Im focusing on the getline for the moment I will look at the allocation in a minute

Comment: It is literally impossible for it to give you the same error, since it would NOT be calling the same method anymore. I suggest you make ALL of the changes I have outlined, and if you are still getting errors after that (I doubt it), then show a screenshot of THAT updated code. Have you looked at the [*working* demo](https://onlinegdb.com/SyJlMu1ud) I provided?